# If I pass a server component to a client component via the children prop, will it be rendered on the client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, rendering

In the NextJS docs, it says [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs) that all child components and modules imported into a client component are considered part of the client bundle. However the docs also say that you can interleave server/client components by passing a server component as children props to a client component in order render the server component on the server e.g.

```js
<ClientComponent>
   <ServerComponent/>
</ClientComponent>
```

I don't understand the difference between these statements or what the verdict exactly is, since these two parts seem to contradict each other. Am I misinterpeting some terminology? Are a client component's children part of the client bundle or are they rendered on the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it's passed as prop (`children` specifically) to `ClientComponent`, `ServerComponent` will not be part of the client bundle. To be sure, try to use `useState` in `ServerComponent` without adding `"use client"` at the top.

When they say *["by defining a `"use client"` in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle"](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs)*, they are talking about modules that you `import` at the top and use in the component body. Not things that are passed as `props`.

They talked about it on [this part of the doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props):

> The following pattern is supported. You can pass Server Components as a prop to a Client Component.
>
> A common pattern is to use the React `children` prop to create a "slot" in your Client Component.
>
> In the example below, `<ClientComponent>` accepts a `children` prop:

```
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({ children }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
 
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

> `<ClientComponent>` doesn't know that `children` will eventually be filled in by the result of a Server Component. The only responsibility `<ClientComponent>` has is to decide where `children` will eventually be placed.
>
> In a parent Server Component, you can import both the `<ClientComponent>` and `<ServerComponent>` and pass `<ServerComponent>` as a child of `<ClientComponent>`:

```
// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what the docs refer to when they say "child components and modules imported into a client component are considered part of the client bundle", since the code you show as an example uses child components but you're saying they aren't part of the client bundle?

Comment: When they say imported modules, they are talking about modules that you import with `import` at the top and use in the component body. Not things that are passed as props.

Comment: In the docs, it specifically says "Once you define the boundary, all child components and modules imported into it are considered part of the client bundle". What does it mean by child components if not those passed as props?

Comment: A child here is a component you call in the component body. For example, in the above ClientComponent, `button` is a child. `chidlren` is a prop.

Comment: To be sure, try to use `useState` in `ServerComponent` without adding `use client` at the top.

Comment: Hi @Sylith, have you checked mu latest edit?

Comment: I've just seen it now. Thanks very much for your response!